# Display a PDF in a Xamarin WebView

Tags: c#, android, pdf, xamarin, xamarin.android

How can I download a PDF file and display it within a WebView without using an external rendering engine?

```cs
WebView webview = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
webview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
webview.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
webview.LoadUrl("http://www.justadomain.com/document.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The web engine is not capable of doing this!**

If you want to display a PDF anyway you need a way to convert it to some kind of HTML. There are many tools regarding this, for example [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com) or [Mozillas PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
webview.LoadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+"http://www.justadomain.com/document.pdf");
```

Comment: Yeah I know this way but I want to show a normal pdf without any renders or javascript wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

There are also many Xamarin components that offer PDF SDKs, but are unfortunately costly. For other free alternatives, you can always check this [blog post](http://subodhjena.com/2016/03/12/xamarin-displaying-pdf-files-on-android-webview/) which states the options you have when displaying PDF files in your application.

The easiest and maybe the cleanest solution is to let a 3rd-party application display your PDF file. Here is the java code taken from the blog post above:

```
using Uri = Android.Net.Uri;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
intent.SetDataAndType(Uri.Parse("file:///" + PathToFile(filename)), "application/pdf");
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
StartActivity(intent);
return null;
```

Otherwise, you can also try to find a PDF library for Android like [this one](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) and, via java bindings, import it into your Xamarin project.

Hope this helps.